# Overload assets/views of a mountable engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-engines

I'm developing a Rails-3.1 Mountable Engine that would be mounted in a rails application, the engine provide it's own assets and views of course but I would like to overload some the files.

Example:

Let's consider a mountable blogging engine, which would be mounted in whatever application to get the blogging system but the engine should look exactly like the website so I would like to overload some asset files as well as some of the views (like the _header and _footer partials rendered in the layout)

Is that possible with mountable engines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely possible. Basically, Rails will always use the files found in the Rails app instead of those coming from the engine.

to redefine views, simply recreate them in your app with same path & name.

Concerning the assets, it's the same principle, I've already done that with javascript (never with pics or css but I assume this is the same).

Comment: I tried this before asking the question, the thing I missed is defining another application.css which required different files names from the one defined in the engine.. This time I did not define another application.css but instead the target sass file and it worked.. Thank you!